# youtube-v3-api security certificate renewal

Tags: ssl, youtube, ssl-certificate, youtube-data-api

We are required to add certificate for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos to our trusted certificates on our servers for complying with security policies.

We noticed that the certificate expires on the 24th of November,2016. Can someone help with a support team mailing list which we can contact to get the new certificate in advance so that there is no outage for the functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a basic concept of TLS: the role of a certificate issuer.

You usually don't lock yourself to a specific certificate for a site and hope that somebody will provide you with the new certificate up front if the old certificate expires and that you then can change all your clients to accept this new certificate. This simply would not scale.

Instead you trust an issuer (CA - certificate agency) to issue a certificate for a specific site. Then you check for any certificate you got that the trust chain to your locally trusted certificate is fine and that the subject of the certificate matches the site you access. The same CA certificate (or at least the public key inside) will be used for many years to issue new certificates, contrary to leaf certificates which are only valid for 1..3 years or even a few month only to reduce the risk of compromise.

In summary: Don't expect anybody to tell you up front when they issue a new certificate because nobody will tell you. Instead do it like everybody else and trust a CA.

Comment: Actually been advised to do so in a security scan. Following links provide details https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/vulncat/java/insecure_ssl_overly_broad_certificate_trust.html https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning

Comment: @megbhandari: since Google will simply not notify everybody when they issue a new certificate you cannot pin to that certificate. You can pin to the public key and hope that they keep the key on renewal or you could pin to a specific issuer, like Google Internet Authority G2.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: you can't. Validate the certificate using CA list.**

Google already use a pinning mechanism in chrome:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json

But www.googleapi.com is not pinned in that list (only translate.googleapis.com), it means google didn't ensure anything about his keys/certificate/certificate chain. So **you can't pin it without taking the risk to break something, even before the renewal**: they could change the certificate and/or the chain without notice.